# How to re-use MS Surface power supply

Tags: power-supply

I had a chance to get 10 Chargers Model 1706 15V 4A 65W with USB charging port for Surface Book, Surface Laptop, Surface Pro, Surface Pro 4 and Surface Pro 3 with cut off connector.

My plan was to use them as a regular 15V power supplies for some other devices.

As it was mentioned here: [MS Surface power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221620/ms-surface-power-supply#new-answer?newreg=40516c8b4ea64be6af83f23756bafcf5) -
something needs to be done with CRTL blue wire.

Any thoughts or ideas how to do that?

I tried to connect this blue wire to the ground - no 15V output.
The same result when I connected it to red 12V wire

Thanks

Comment: please provide the power supply schematic diagram

Comment: So, is it 12V or 15V output? From link, you provided, the blue wire should kept floating, overvise out pulsing.

Comment: @jsotola
The schematics is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221620/ms-surface-power-supply#new-answer?newreg=40516c8b4ea64be6af83f23756bafcf5


Thanks

Comment: @user263983
It's written 15V on the power supply, but the schematics says 12V.
If I leave a blue wire floating (not connected?) - I have pulsing voltage on the output
But I want 15V.
Thanks

Comment: Question is: if I leave or then I leave? Are you guessing or tested? I looked at schematic at the post, you linked.

Comment: @user263983

I did try that.

When I left a blue wire floating (not connected?) - I have pulsing voltage on the output. 

When I connected blue wire to the ground wire -  I have pulsing voltage on the output. 

When I connected it to red 12V wire -  I have pulsing voltage on the output. 

Thanks

Comment: So, the schematic on linked post is wrong. The blue wire may be some data interface.